# Default.png is shown misplaced

Tags: ios

After updating iPhone to iOS 5.1 and Xcode to 4.3.1, I rebuilt the app to test compatibility.
Except `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` is removed, every thing goes well.

But a strange issue occurred, the launching screen had a while line under the "Default.png". Has anyone met the same issue before? Thanks for any tips.

Comment: I haven't upgraded to 4.3.1 yet, but does that white line happen to be 20 px tall?

Comment: @fichek just about 5px tall, I changed some pictures, they were fine

Comment: Make sure to [submit a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com) if you are sure your Default.png was right size.

Comment: Finally solved this issue by changing the Default.png formate from png8 to png24. @fichek

Comment: Interesting. You should submit that as answer and accept it to mark the question resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved this issue by changing the Default.png formate from png8 to png24. Strange issue in iOS sdk 5.1 or Xcode 4.3.1

Comment: strange. nothings wrong with png8.. you should file a bug to apple.